# .NET 5.0 breaking changes regarding `IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy` behavior on string comparison

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I have below code

```
    public class Model
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var models = new List<Model>
            {
                new Model {Id = 4, OrderNumber = "BT-3964-1"},
                new Model {Id = 2, OrderNumber = "BT3924"},
                new Model {Id = 1, OrderNumber = "bt3810v2"},
                new Model {Id = 5, OrderNumber = "BILL-TEST100"},
                new Model {Id = 3, OrderNumber = "BT-4887-Test3-Create"}
            };

            var reorderedModels = models.OrderBy(x => x.OrderNumber);

            Console.WriteLine("The sorted models are:");
            foreach (var model in reorderedModels)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"OrderNumber: {model.OrderNumber}, Id: {model.Id}");
            }
        }
    }
```

In .NET Core 3.1 and 2.1, it gives below output

```
The sorted models are:
OrderNumber: BILL-TEST100, Id: 5
OrderNumber: bt3810v2, Id: 1
OrderNumber: BT3924, Id: 2
OrderNumber: BT-3964-1, Id: 4
OrderNumber: BT-4887-Test3-Create, Id: 3
```

But on .NET 5.0, it gives below output

```
The sorted models are:
OrderNumber: BILL-TEST100, Id: 5
OrderNumber: BT-3964-1, Id: 4
OrderNumber: BT-4887-Test3-Create, Id: 3
OrderNumber: bt3810v2, Id: 1
OrderNumber: BT3924, Id: 2
```

Why the breaking changes?

***Additional Note***: even using `OrderBy(x => x.OrderNumber, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`, this issue still happens

Comment: Interestingly this also happens even if you use `.OrderBy(x => x.OrderNumber, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`;

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Will update the question to point that out

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm guessing it has something to do with the change to use International Components for Unicode (ICU) libraries as the default.

You can read about it specifically as it affects string comparison here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus

An example given is for sorting strings. Their example is about instantiating a `SortedtSet<string>`, but the logic in the solution can be extended to cover your use of `OrderBy` by providing the explicit comparer you want to use.

The example:

```
//
// Potentially incorrect code - behavior might vary based on locale.
//
SortedSet<string> mySet = new SortedSet<string>();
List<string> list = GetListOfStrings();
list.Sort();

//
// Corrected code - uses ordinal sorting; doesn't vary by locale.
//
SortedSet<string> mySet = new SortedSet<string>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
List<string> list = GetListOfStrings();
list.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Answer (score 1):

What @Loggar said and for your specific case to get consistent behaviour the change will be to pass the string comparer to `OrderBy`:

```
.OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Even though you're right by saying he can pass the `StringComparer` to `OrderBy`, your answer could be misleading as you use `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`, which is not working. So updating your answer to use `StringComparer.Ordinal` would be great.